# Windows Server 2012 RemoteAccess 20106

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows, rras

I was running RRAS on my Windows Server 2012 before and now I uninstalled the role but I still get an Event ID 20106 from RemoteAccess which says

```
Unable to add the interface {guid} with the Router Manager for the IP protocol. 
The following error occurred: Cannot complete this function.
```

Any idea why RA would be putting this out even though the only role I have installed is Hyper-V?

Comment: Did you "unconfigure" RA before removing the role?

Comment: You can't remove RA without unconfiguring it.